# На каком языке программирования написана Windows XP и 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7

На каком языке программирования написана Windows XP и 7?

Comment: Конечно на php!

Comment: ))) а я то дурак, голову ломаю... вы просто гений!!!)))

Comment: Хорошо еще, что паскаль и бейсик не предлагаются, хотя насчет последнего надо сказать, что действительно некоторые компоненты ОСи на нем написаны.

Comment: php devel studio инфа сотка

Answer (score 20):

На самом деле они написаны не на одном языке программирования, а на смеси:

- большая часть - С/С++ (с Visual Studio)
- небольшая часть - ассемблер (masm, какой же ещё)
- С# (этого в ХР изначально не было, а вот для 7 - уже много)
- hta (это такой способ делать приложения с помощью html и скриптов).

Есть такая байка (не знаю, на сколько правдивая, но очень интересная), что Висту изначально хотели написать полностью на С# и .NET языках. Типа было бы очень круто (все было бы очень стабильно и круто). Но потом поняли, что это просто невозможно (как минимум - ещё нет такого железа, что бы оно все взлетело). И сделали по старинке - допилили XP.

Если есть интерес к тому, как оно там устроено внутри, то можно посмотреть на ReactOs - это попытка сделать windows совместимую операционную систему.

Comment: Не согласен. Действительно, XP собрана с применением Microsoft C/C++ compiler'а. Но специфика в том, что бОльшая часть операционной системы собрана именно как Си-код без всяких новомодных фич вроде ООП. Прикладные программы (по крайней мере часть) - да, днйствительно собраны как настоящие c++ приложения.

Comment: Касательно visual studio - тоже не совсем верно. Способ сборки операционной системы больше напоминает то, как это реализовано в XP DDK, т.е. с помощью конфигурационных файлов и специализированной утилиты build. Если бы делалось через студию - это ж застрелиться можно было бы, т.к. целей доя сборки в ОC over 1000...

Comment: Я думаю, это всем понятно, что каждый раз все не перекомпилируют, а берут готовое - каждый компилит свой небольшой кусок. А потом какой то хитрый скрипт/програмка собирает все в один iso/образ для виртуальной машины. Поэтому нет никаких страшных over1000 файлов. Ну может только в некоторых отделах.
Например, сидит себе человек и клепает "Панель Управления" и апплеты к ней. И ему не обязательно ядро пересобирать на каждый чих.

Comment: Процесс автоматизирован. И происходит на отдельных серверах. Касательно целей для сборки - речь о том, что каждый отдельный компонент - отдельная цель. Т.е. отдельно панель управления и каждый апплет по отдельности. Таким способом обеспечивается независимость. Т.е. можно править любой элемент, не пересобирая все подряд. И вижуал студия тупо умрет, если в нее запихать такое кол-во файлов. Сколь там исполняемых файлов плюс библиотек в винде? И каждая состоит минимум из десятка исходных файлов.

Answer (score 6):

Разные части на разных языках программирования, но основная часть — на С++, часть - ассемблер. 
Весь код компилированый и содержится в виде машинного кода